# Construct hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Given some Data $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}$ we are interested in constructing a $\textbf{consistent}$ hypothesis test for
$H_{0}:\theta =\theta _{0}$ vs. $H_{1}:\theta \neq \theta_{0}$. 
Suppose that there is a weak convergence result such as under $H_{0}$
$\alpha_{n}(T_{n}-\theta)\rightarrow X$ in distribution holds. Furthermore, the distribution of $X$ may be known. 
So is the following testing procedure appropriate?

**reject** $H_{0}$ if $\left|T_{n}\right|\geq c\alpha_{n}^{-1}+\theta_{0}$ for some $c$?

If yes, why?
if not, why?
Again, I am only interested in constructing a consistent test.

Comment: Is this for some class? Can you be more explicit about where your difficulties are?

Comment: @Glen_b I added some further information.

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't work, because your manipulation of terms didn't maintain the relationship between the components correctly.

You have something that's asymptotically a pivotal quantity $Q_n=α_n(T_n−θ)$ (asymptotically it's distributed as $X$, where $F_X(x)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$). Work out your limits on $Q_n(\theta)$ using $F$ and back out the asymptotic limits on $T_n$.

Consider the situation under the null ($\theta=\theta_0$). You can find two quantiles $x_l$ and $x_u$ where $F_X(x_l) + 1-F_X(x_u)$ is the desired significance level (I'm there assuming this is continuous, its a teeny bit more fiddly in the general case, because you would include $p(x_u)$ in there, or write it as $1-F_X(x_u^-)\,$), and then reject when $\alpha_n(T_n-\theta_0)$ lies outside $(x_l,x_u)$.

You can then convert that to a rejection rule directly in terms of $T_n$.

Beware - there's nothing in your question that established that the distribution of $X$ is symmetric.

Comment: For a level $\alpha$ test it should work as follows:
The Type I Error should equal $\alpha$. That is, $1-(F_{X}(\frac{x_{i}}{\alpha_{n}}+\theta_{0})-F_{X}(\frac{x_{u}}{\alpha_{n}}+\theta_{0}))=\alpha$ yields the choice of $(x_{l},x_{u})$. But is it possible to simplify the whole stuff, if I am only interested in consistency of the test?

Comment: Your rejection rule seems to rely on an assumption that $|T_n|$ will converge to $\theta_0$ if the null hypothesis is true. ... but even leaving that aside are you really saying you don't care what the level is?

Comment: In a first step, yes. I just want to construct a consistent test. I don't care about $\alpha$.

Comment: Then simply reject every time; you'll always reject the null when its false.

Comment: Ok, then it doesn't make sense what I have intended. How then I have to work out the test, if I want a consistent one?

Comment: If $\alpha_n$ increases suitably with $n$ then the test in my answer is consistent. My answer fulfills the condition, so it's not clear what more you require.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha_{n}$ increases suitably?

Comment: So, in order to prove consistency, we have to show, that the test ensures asymptotically, the right decision, that is.
(a) For $n\rightarrow \infty$ $P(\text{reject }H_{0}\text{ if it is false})\rightarrow 1$
(b) For $n\rightarrow \infty$ $P(\text{reject }H_{1}\text{ if it is false})\rightarrow 1$
right?

Comment: You never reject $H_1$; you either reject or fail to reject $H_0$. Consistency in a test is defined (slightly loosely) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)#Tests). If you hold the significance level constant as $n$ increases, then the probability of rejection of a false null goes to $1$. So if you plot rejection probability vs $\theta$ at some $n$ you get a curve through $\alpha$ (or at least not above it) at $\theta=\theta_0$ that (hopefully) increases toward $1$ as you move away from $\theta_0$, ... ctd

Comment: ... and then if you plot new such curves at a sequence of increasing sample sizes, the minimum stays $\leq \alpha$ but the curve gets steeper and steeper, approaching a jump up to $1$ as you move away from $\theta=\theta_0$. I expect your text or notes will have it defined more carefully but that's the gist of it. The definition [here](https://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node80.html) (Def. 9.4) would be reasonable if it was clear there that the approach to $1$ was as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: On the "increase suitably" note that $\alpha_n$ must increase as $n$ increases to get the power curve to tighten, but simply increasing is not sufficient. I didn't want to make a needlessly technical point, but loosely it has to go off to infinity to make the rejection probability for $\theta\neq\theta_0$ go to $1$ as $n$ increases. Typically $\alpha_n$ will be $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$. If I had just said "increase" you could have $\alpha_n$ going as $2-\frac{1}{n}$ or something, which doesn't work. You have to make the appropriate form of converge happen there for the definition of consistency